# 500 error when attempting to .get() another file in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am attempting to do some simple Express routing. However, whenever I attempt to retrieve data to link to a new page on my website, I get a 500 error instead. My Index.js file is for routing.

Index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('monk')('localhost:27017/');
var userData = db.get('user-data');
var app = require('express')();

router.get('/', function(req,res,next){
    res.render('layout');
});

router.get('/1', function(req,res,next){
    res.render('layout2');
});


module.exports = router;
```

My app.js file contains my app engine, which is in fact set up for handlebars:

```
app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

Here is what the error says:

```
GET / 500 33.765 ms - 20931
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1.633 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/print2.css 304 1.219 ms - -
```

I expect that when I type in localhost:8000/1 the site will render layout2.hbs - but I get a 500 error instead.

Comment: Look at the the error message.

Comment: Post the error.

Comment: Did you restart the server after adding the route?

Comment: I have attempted to restart the server after adding the route but receive the same error.

Comment: Have you see the engine to use handlebars?

Comment: Yes, the app engine is set to handlebars in my app.js file

Comment: You might want to use `res.render(layout: 'layout2')`in your second router.get call.

Comment: could you post the app/server code

Answer (score 0):

GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1.633 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/print2.css 304 1.219 ms - -

These error may be because you have not specified static folder for your app.
Create a static public folder in your project root directory.

Add all your local css, js, and images in a file named "public" and add the below middleware code in your index.js file.

```
app.use(express.static("public"))
```

Hope this will solve our problem.

Comment: I have done all that @Deepak Sharma suggested and still 'layout2' will not render if I type in '/1' into the localhost. Instead, I get the message: "GET / 304 30.902 ms - -
GET /style.css 304 3.370 ms - -
GET /print2.css 304 0.553 ms - -
GET /1 304 9.213 ms - -"